# How to update website with the translated xml file in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am looking into creating a multilingual website using umbraco v7 ,and used one website per language approach.

My Scenario is,
   Author(Administrator) sends a website for translation to the translator,and the translator can download the XML files of that particular website for translation into the specified language.After translation translator update the same and upload it into umbraco.

My issue is,
   After translator uploaded the XML file in umbraco,there is a "preview" option for the page,

[it retrieves the following error: image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W95mZ.png)

Comment: See the following blog post: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2013/the-dictionary-secrets/